# Sharp command failed

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, sharp

[image: screen with error code]

Here is my error message:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\projects\resmix-crm-app\frontend\node_modules\favicons\node_modules\sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! info sharp Using cached C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_libvips\libvips-8.8.1-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! info sharp Creating C:\projects\resmix-crm-app\frontend\node_modules\favicons\node_modules\sharp\build\Release
npm ERR! info sharp Copying DLLs from C:\projects\resmix-crm-app\frontend\node_modules\favicons\node_modules\sharp\vendor\lib to C:\projects\resmix-crm-app\frontend\node_modules\favicons\node_modules\sharp\build\Release
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.0.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python311\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1062:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:448:11)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\projects\\resmix-crm-app\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\projects\resmix-crm-app\frontend\node_modules\favicons\node_modules\sharp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

I tried to demolish the Node.js completely and reinstall, cleaned its tails in the `AppData` folder, installed sharp separately, nothing helps, who has faced a similar problem?